# matching text between two different data frames in R

Tags: r, text, matching

I have the following data in a data frame:

```
structure(list(`head(ker$text)` = structure(1:6, .Label = c("@_rpg_17 little league travel tourney. These parents about to be wild.", 
"@auscricketfan @davidwarner31 yes WI tour is coming soon", "@keralatourism #favourite #destination #munnar #topstation https://t.co/sm9qz7Z9aR", 
"@NWAWhatsup tour of duty in NWA considered a dismal assignment?  Companies send in their best ppl and then those ppl don't want to leave", 
"Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala-prime tourist attractions of India.Visit:http://t.co/zFCoaoqCMP http://t.co/zaGNd0aOBy", 
"Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala, God's own country, is one of the prime tourist attractions of... http://t.co/FLZrEo7NpO"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "head(ker$text)", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have another data frame that contains hashtags extracted from the above data frame.  It is as follows:

```
structure(list(destination = c("#topstation", "#destination", "#munnar", 
"#Kerala", "#Delhi", "#beach")), .Names = "destination", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new column in my first data frame, which will have contain only the tags matched with the second data frame.  For example, the first line of df1 does not have any hashtags, hence this cell in the new column will be blank.  However, the second line contains 4 hashtags, of which three of them are matching with the second data frame.  I have tried using:

```
str_match
str_extract
```

functions.  I came very close to getting this using a code given in one of the posts here.

```
new_col <- ker[unlist(lapply(destn$destination, agrep, ker$text)), ]
```

While I understand, I am getting a list as an output I am getting an error indicating

```
replacement has 1472 rows, data has 644
```

I have tried setting max.distance to different parameters, each gave me differential errors.  Can someone help me with a solution?  One alternative which I am thinking of is to have each hashtag in a separate column, but not sure if it will help me in analysing the data further with other variables that I have. The output I am looking for is as follows:

```
text          new_col          new_col2    new_col3
statement1    
statement2
statement3    #destination     #munnar     #topstation
statement4
statement5    #Kerala
statement6    #Kerala
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringi);
df1$tags <- sapply(stri_extract_all(df1[[1]],regex='#\\w+'),function(x) paste(x[x%in%df2[[1]]],collapse=','));
df1;
##                                                                                                                             head(ker$text)                             tags
## 1                                                                   @_rpg_17 little league travel tourney. These parents about to be wild.
## 2                                                                                 @auscricketfan @davidwarner31 yes WI tour is coming soon
## 3                                                       @keralatourism #favourite #destination #munnar #topstation https://t.co/sm9qz7Z9aR #destination,#munnar,#topstation
## 4 @NWAWhatsup tour of duty in NWA considered a dismal assignment?  Companies send in their best ppl and then those ppl don't want to leave
## 5     Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala-prime tourist attractions of India.Visit:http://t.co/zFCoaoqCMP http://t.co/zaGNd0aOBy                          #Kerala
## 6   Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala, God's own country, is one of the prime tourist attractions of... http://t.co/FLZrEo7NpO                          #Kerala
```

**Edit:** If you want a separate column for each tag:

```
library(stringi);
m <- sapply(stri_extract_all(df1[[1]],regex='#\\w+'),function(x) x[x%in%df2[[1]]]);
df1 <- cbind(df1,do.call(rbind,lapply(m,`[`,1:max(sapply(m,length)))));
df1;
##                                                                                                                             head(ker$text)            1       2           3
## 1                                                                   @_rpg_17 little league travel tourney. These parents about to be wild.         <NA>    <NA>        <NA>
## 2                                                                                 @auscricketfan @davidwarner31 yes WI tour is coming soon         <NA>    <NA>        <NA>
## 3                                                       @keralatourism #favourite #destination #munnar #topstation https://t.co/sm9qz7Z9aR #destination #munnar #topstation
## 4 @NWAWhatsup tour of duty in NWA considered a dismal assignment?  Companies send in their best ppl and then those ppl don't want to leave         <NA>    <NA>        <NA>
## 5     Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala-prime tourist attractions of India.Visit:http://t.co/zFCoaoqCMP http://t.co/zaGNd0aOBy      #Kerala    <NA>        <NA>
## 6   Are you Looking for a trip to Kerala? #Kerala, God's own country, is one of the prime tourist attractions of... http://t.co/FLZrEo7NpO      #Kerala    <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: Many many thanks, bgoldst , it worked!... whew...that was a complex one for me...thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
results <- sapply(df$`head(ker$text)`, 
                  function(x) { str_match_all(x, paste(df2$destination, collapse = "|")) })

df$matches <- results
```

If you want to separate the results out, you can use:

`df <- cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(results,`[`, 1:max(sapply(results, length)))))`

Comment: Many thanks JasonAiskalns....I worked partially, providing me both the statement as well as the hashtag....I would require only the hashtags...I have updated the query again indicating the output

Comment: I tried using your code by changing str_match_all to str_match...got the output...  but provided only one of the hashtag for statement 3 instead of 3 hashtags....

Comment: @MageshGovindan Are you sure, when I look at `df` and look at the `match` column for statement 3, I see all three hashtags separated by a comma.